# How to keep apps open in full screen OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, applications, spaces, fullscreen

I have been trying to find a way to keep my windows opening in full screen mode.  I have tried to open them in full screen and then close them without resizing the screen, but then when I restart my computer the windows default back to a small screen and it gets very frustrating trying to navigate to another window.  Is there a way to set the mac up so it defaults to full screen mode when opening an app (for example chrome).

Comment: could you elaborate on how you are making your apps full screen?   Are you using the green button at the top left of the window?  the diagonal arrows at the top right of the window?  or a menu command?

Answer (score 1):

Most OS X apps will open in the last state they were in before quitting. So if you quit an application on fullscreen mode it should open in full screen mode when you launch the app again.

In the case of Chrome you will need to tick the "Continue where you left off" option on the startup section of settings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not the default behavior for some apps, such as the app store.